# how to initilize the set using static set of another class...?

Tags: c++, set

```
class A{
static set<string> set1;
};

class B{
set<string> set2;
public:
A a;
}

in main.cpp
void B::comparision()
{
set2.insert(a.set1);   //i am getting error
};
```

how can i initilize `set2` with the value of `set1`.

Comment: Any sane developer would recommend not to name a method/function after actions it does not perform, i.e. do not name 'comparison' a method performing an assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first you'll need `A::set1` to be publicly accessible:

```
class A {
    public:
        static set<string> set1;
}
```

You can also remove `a` from your definition of `B`, since you don't need an instance of `A`, you only need to access one of its static public members.

Then your `comparison` function should be modified as follows:

```
void B::comparison()
{
    set2 = A::set1;
}
```

Note that `insert` takes a single value and inserts it into the set.  This will not suffice to copy an entire set.  Fortunately, you have an assignment operator you can use as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `void B::comparison()` is since you never declared it, but the general syntax would be:

```
set2 = A::set1;
```

The exception to that syntax would be if `set2` were being initialized (i.e., in a class constructor), in which case it would look like:

```
B::B : set2(A::set1) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

By initialize I assume you want to copy all elements of the static set to the set in class B (without preserving its previous contents). In such case, you need to assign it as `set2 = A::set1;`

Comment: @Mat: yes. I assumed OP has fixed those types of errors and is looking for the syntax to access the static element of another class.

Answer (score 0):

The static data member is shared by all objects of the class, so it is not a part of any object. In this case, set1 is not a part of object `a`. So you cannot access it by a.set1. Instead you can access the static data member by `A::set1`. As already said by others, you need `A::set1` to be publicly accessible.

And if you want to insert `A::set1` into `set2`, the code would look like:
`set2.insert(A::set1.begin(), A::set1.end())`